# Find star rating

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

On this [page](https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/3475783/Xiaolan-Zhao-Toronto-ON.html) I am trying to find a star rating.

In scrapy shell:

```
len(response.css('#info-panel .selected'))

len(response.css('#info-panel').xpath('//*[has-class("star selected")]'))
```

But nothing works out.

html

```html
<div class="search-item-info" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3">
  <span doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0">
  <span class="star-rating" title="3.92" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0">
  <span class="stars" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0">
  <span class="star" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0.$5"></span>
  <span class="star selected" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0.$4"></span>
  <span class="star selected" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0.$3"></span>
  <span class="star selected" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0.$2"></span>
  <span class="star selected" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0.$1"></span></span>
  </span>
  <div class="star-rating-count" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.1">
    <span doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.1.0">
    <span itemprop="ratingCount" doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.1.0.0">28</span></span>
    <span doctordetail=".1.0.0.0.1.3.0.1.1"> reviews</span></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
response.css(".star-rating::attr(title)").get()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you get a 403 error (leading to an empty response) since the website uses Cloudfare protection. Then, you should probably use https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape to bypass it.

If that's not the case, you can use one of the following XPath expression to get your star rating :

```
count(//h1/following::span[@class="stars"][1]//span[@class="star selected"])
```

Output : 4

More precise :

```
substring-before(substring-after(//script[contains(@type,"json")],'"ratingValue": "'),'"')
```

Output : 3.9

Comment: i got an error:
  
`count(//h1/following::span[@class="stars"][1]//span[@class="star selected"])
          
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Are you sure you get the page correctly (no 403 error because of the Cloudfare protection) ? What's the output of `requests.status_code` ?